# Can I change the 256 color mappings in iterm2 or Terminal?

Tags: terminal, iterm2

For example, I'd like to change the color "52" found in this [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg) to a much darker red.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a way to create a color theme. I want to redefine the underlining color that are mapped to the standard 256 colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change those mappings as a part of iTerm or Terminal configuration.